# C# outofmemory exception when enumerating anonymous collection

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use a linq query to pair records together based on matching fields.

Obviously this means when the collection is created there are duplicate records where more than 2 records match on the same field.

I am dealing with this duplication afterwards.

The problem I am having is when I enumerate the anonymous collection, which is a collection of type new {record1, record2}, I am getting an out of memory exception.

Without naming the fields, the records are of the following type:

```
public class record {
    public CustomEnum myType {get; set;}
    public int myPrimaryKey {get; set;}
    public DateTime? myDate {get; set;}
    public String myString1 {get; set;}
    public String myString2 {get; set;}
    public String myString3 {get; set;}
    public decimal? myDecimal {get; set;}
};
```

The class has no methods.

Any suggestions for how to reduce the memory usage for this collection? If I were using C++ I'd use references. In C# it appears to copy the whole record object every time it appears in a new matched pair, resulting in masses of wasted memory

Comment: I'd suggest a dictionary since the key is unique

Comment: Post code which throws OOMException

Comment: how do you "pair" records ?

Comment: "In C# it appears to copy the whole record": it does not. Classes are always references. Maybe you should match before you join because an unmatched join may well be huge depending on your data.

Comment: @Mark, show please your query

Comment: No it is not copied every time as you have a class and not a struct. Profile your issue first.

Comment: I am matching when I join. Joining on, in this case, record1.myString1 = record2.myString1

Comment: How many records are there, and how many of them can have an identical myString1 (e.g. empty)?

Comment: I'm not looking for cases where myString1 is empty. There are cases where myString1 is not empty but is identical in other records, which is what I am matching on. There are approximately 160 000 records to match I think

Comment: What's the origin of the data? Any chance you can do this by LINQ to an SQL backend?

Comment: @Mark, _if_ there are a lot of empty records, you are matching every single one of them with all the others. so if you have 100000 empty myString1, you have 10000000000 matches. Hence my questions. How many records, how many with myString1 = empty? Because you _are_ matching those, whether they are of interest or not. Or maybe you are not but why should we kep guessing? Why not show us the code?

Comment: because I'm ignoring nulls in my query, so those records don't get found. I have found another way to do this now anyway, I did all my matching manually in code rather than using Linq. Turned out to be significantly faster as well